# jquery switchery need to limit the number of selected switches

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox, switchery

I have a page with multiple checkboxes for selecting various options, and the user is allowed to select up to 6 options only.

I had this fully working with standard html checkboxes fine, using the following code:

```
$('.ios-switch').on('click', function(e) {
var num_checked = 0;
$('.ios-switch').each(function() { if ($(this).prop('checked')) { num_checked++; } });
if (num_checked > 6) { $(this).prop('checked', false); }
});
```

I have since added the jquery switchery library, to turn the checkboxes into iOS style switches.

I set this up using the code:

```
var elems = Array.prototype.slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('.ios-switch'));
elems.forEach(function(html) {
var switchery = new Switchery(html, { size: 'small' });
});
```

Which works fine for styling all the checkboxes on the page, but now the first bit of code that limits the number of selections no longer works.

I have tried various snippets of code and methods from the switchery site, but I am unable to get back the functionality I had at the start, whereby the user is only allowed to select a maximum of 6 options.

Comment: Did you change the class of the elements when you started using switchery?  In other words, are there still '.checkbox' elements for your js to limit?

Comment: This was an error in my original post, now corrected. All checkboxes have a class of ".ios-switch" and both sets of code are set to reference this class.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you need to use a simple `change` event-handler:

```
function limitChecksTo(n) {

  // ensures the passed-in number is a Number,
  // even if entered as a String (eg: '6');
  n = parseInt(n, 10);

  // converting the NodeList from document.querySelectorAll()
  // into an Array (ECMAScript 6):
  var checkboxes = Array.from(

      // finding all the <input> elements whose type is 'checkbox'
      // and have a class-name of 'ios-switch':
      document.querySelectorAll('input[type=checkbox].ios-switch')
      );

  // 'this' is passed in automatically
  // from EventTarget.addEventListener()
  // and is the element that has the
  // event-listener attached:
  this.checked = checkboxes

  // filtering the array of checkboxes to retain
  // only those that are checked (using Arrow functions)
    .filter(checkbox => checkbox.checked)
  // if the length is less than n + 1 we
  // we set the checked state of the element firing
  // the event to true, otherwise to false:
    .length < n + 1;
}

// iterating over the 'elems' using Array.prototype.forEach():
elems.forEach(function (html) {
  var switchery = new Switchery(html, { size: 'small' });

  // setting the limitChecksTo() function as the
  // event-handler for the 'change' event:
  html.addEventListener('change', limitChecksTo(6));
});
```

References:

- [`Array.from()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from).
- [`Array.prototype.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter).
- [`Array.prototype.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach).
- [Arrow Functions (`=>`)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions).
- [`document.querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll).
- [`EventTarget.addEventListener()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener).

Comment: Seems there is a sytax error in this line: .filter(checkbox => checkbox.checked)

Comment: I haven't tested, but it *looks* correct; can I ask which browser you're using?

Comment: Do they report any error with this JS Fiddle, which uses similar Arrow functions: https://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/pocn0j45/

Answer (score 0):

Wasn't able to get this working with switchery, and it looked like any solution was going to be very complex.

In the end, I found another jquery library, iosCheckbox, which is much simpler to use and control.

http://www.jqueryscript.net/form/iOS-Style-Checkbox-Plugin-with-jQuery-CSS3-iosCheckbox-js.html

I was able to style the CSS to get iosCheckbox to look exactly like switchery, so no noticeable front end difference, but the back end code is much smaller and I got my solution working a lot quicker!